# Phpunit testing callback functions when passing them to a stub method

Tags: phpunit, guzzle

Here is the method to test.

```
public function performPoolRequest(RecreationRequestsCollection $requests): RecreatedPaymentsPoolReading
{
    $count_request = count($requests);

    if($count_request) {
        $pool_recreate_payments = new RecreatedPaymentsPool();

        $this->http_client->sendPoolRequest(
            $this->generateRequests($requests),
            $count_request,
            function (ResponseInterface $response, $index) use ($requests, $pool_recreate_payments) {
                $this->successHandler($response, $requests, $index, $pool_recreate_payments);
            },
            function (BadResponseException $reason, $index) use ($requests, $pool_recreate_payments) {
                $this->failureHandler($reason, $requests, $index, $pool_recreate_payments);
            }
        );

        return $pool_recreate_payments;
    } else {
        throw new PoolRequestException('Incorrect amount of requests: ' . $count_request);
    }
}
```

Difficulties arose with this piece of code:

```
    $this->http_client->sendPoolRequest(
        $this->generateRequests($requests),
        $count_request,
        function (ResponseInterface $response, $index) use ($requests, $pool_recreate_payments) {
            $this->successHandler($response, $requests, $index, $pool_recreate_payments);
        },
        function (BadResponseException $reason, $index) use ($requests, $pool_recreate_payments) {
            $this->failureHandler($reason, $requests, $index, $pool_recreate_payments);
        }
    );
```

I made a mock object `$this->http_client`
But I don't know how to test methods in the argumets ($this->successHandler, $this->failureHandler, this->generateRequests($requests)) that are sent to the method sendPoolRequest.
All of these methods are protected. I understand how to test them using a reflection object, but I want to know if there is an option to test them within a single test by checking the values in $ pool_recreate_payments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fake what the http client is doing in some way. That means: actually calling the callback functions. While it might be possible to do that with a PHPUnit mock object, writing own test doubles is often easier.

Here are a few examples to get you started.

```php
public function testAllFailing()
{
    $client = new class implements HttpClient {
        public function sendPoolRequest(array $requests, int $numRequests, callable $successHandler, callable $errorHandler)
        {
            foreach ($requests as $index => $request) {
                $errorHandler(new BadResponseException(/*...*/), $index);
            }
        }
    };

    $myService = new MyService($client);
    $result = $myService->performPoolRequest(/*...*/);

    self::assertEquals(/*...*/, $result);
}

public function testAllSucceeding()
{
    $client = new class implements HttpClient {
        public function sendPoolRequest(array $requests, int $numRequests, callable $successHandler, callable $errorHandler)
        {
            foreach ($requests as $index => $request) {
                $successHandler(new Response(/*...*/), $index);
            }
        }
    };

    $myService = new MyService($client);
    $result = $myService->performPoolRequest(/*...*/);

    self::assertEquals(/*...*/, $result);
}

public function testEveryOtherFails()
{
    $client = new class implements HttpClient {
        public function sendPoolRequest(array $requests, int $numRequests, callable $successHandler, callable $errorHandler)
        {
            foreach ($requests as $index => $request) {
                if ($index % 2 === 0) {
                    $successHandler(new Response(/*...*/), $index);
                } else {
                    $errorHandler(new BadResponseException(/*...*/), $index);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $myService = new MyService($client);
    $result = $myService->performPoolRequest(/*...*/);

    self::assertEquals(/*...*/, $result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I don't really like the proposed option. Since I cannot track whether the http client will work correctly when sending a request. But your advice gave me an idea of how to solve my question. Therefore, I thank you all the same)).

Answer (score 0):

Since Guzzle is used as the http client, I decided to use its capabilities in terms of creating stubs for the response object. Here is a link to the documentation [Guzzle documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html#mock-handler). The solution turned out to be simple and allowed us to extensively test the business logic of the response.